# React, how to toggle background color of just one button?

Tags: reactjs, button, styles, toggle

I try to change background color of each button after click. Problem is, that it works for all of the buttons together, instead of just for one which was clicked. I think, that I should use e, or index to fix it, but I really don't know how to do this.

App.js

```
const initialState = [
  {
    person: "Ela",
    age: 48
  },
  {
    person: "Natalia",
    age: 28
  }
];

const green = "#39D1B4";
const yellow = "#FFD712";

export default function App() {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState(initialState);
  const [buttonColor, setButtonColor] = useState(green);

  function handleColorChange(e) {
    const button = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
    const newButton = e.target.style.backgroundColor;

    const newColor = buttonColor === green ? yellow : green;
    setButtonColor(newColor);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {person.map((per, i) => {
        return (
          <Person
            color={buttonColor}
            key={i}
            index={i}
            onClick={handleColorChange}
            person={per}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Person.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function Person({ person, onClick, color, index }) {
  return (
    <>
      <h3>My name is {person.person}</h3>
      <h3>My age is {person.age}</h3>
      <button
        style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
        color={color}
        name={person.person}
        onClick={onClick}
        index={index}
      >
        Change color
      </button>
      {index}
    </>
  );
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does each person have their own color? If person A changes the color, does it only apply to them? Or will person B see the change too?

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply like this. Basically track total person . And based on person number(i.e 0,1) update there respective button value:

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import "./style.css";

const initialState = [
  {
    person: "Ela",
    age: 48
  },
  {
    person: "Natalia",
    age: 28
  }
];

const green = "#39D1B4";
const yellow = "#FFD712";

function Person({ person, onClick, color, index }) {
  return (
    <>
      <h3>My name is {person.person}</h3>
      <h3>My age is {person.age}</h3>
      <button
        style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
        color={color}
        name={person.person}
        onClick={onClick}
        index={index}
      >
        Change color
      </button>
      {index}
    </>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState(initialState);
  const [buttonColor, setButtonColor] = useState({0:green,1:green});

  function handleColorChange(e,i) {
    console.log(i)
    const button = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
    const newButton = e.target.style.backgroundColor;

    const newColor = buttonColor[i] === green ? yellow : green;
    const newState ={...buttonColor,[i]:newColor}
    setButtonColor(newState);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {person.map((per, i) => {
        return (
          <Person
            color={buttonColor[i]}
            key={i}
            index={i}
            onClick={(e) => handleColorChange(e,i)}
            person={per}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3ca52l

Answer (score 0):

You should move logic for changing background color to Person component. Thus, each button will have it's own state with color value.
Cause now you store button color in parent component and share it with all children, that's why when one child changes the color, the other receive this change.

Answer (score 0):

Just move your handleColorChange method and buttonColor state into Person component so color changing will only effect each button for itself like this;

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Person from "./Person";

const initialState = [
  {
    person: "Ela",
    age: 48
  },
  {
    person: "Natalia",
    age: 28
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState(initialState);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {person.map((per, i) => {
        return <Person key={i} index={i} person={per} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Person.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Person({ person, onClick, color, index }) {
  let green = "#39D1B4";
  let yellow = "#FFD712";

  const [buttonColor, setButtonColor] = useState(green);

  function handleColorChange(e) {
    const button = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
    const newButton = e.target.style.backgroundColor;

    const newColor = buttonColor === green ? yellow : green;
    setButtonColor(newColor);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h3>My name is {person.person}</h3>
      <h3>My age is {person.age}</h3>
      <button
        style={{ backgroundColor: buttonColor }}
        color={buttonColor}
        name={person.person}
        onClick={handleColorChange}
        index={index}
      >
        Change color
      </button>
      {index}
    </>
  );
}
```

Working example [over here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-pond-m9cg7?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Set your new color to your button not to state.

```
const newColor = buttonColor === green ? yellow : green;
e.target.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
```

setState call render and all your buttons get color from state.

Or you must have color props in your *Person* and on event change that color. (Than element must get color from Person)