# how can i change the color of the button when clicked (Only the button that was clicked)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I ma trying to make a Quiz App using React.So, I have been trying to use various methods to make a button change its color when clicked (only the button that was clicked) but when I click it all of them change their color. Any solution for making only the button clicked to change its color? in React.js.

App.js

```
import Main from './Main'
import Quiz from './Quiz'
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function App() {

    const [switch1, setSwitch1] = useState(false)
    const [color , setColor] = useState(false)

    const qanda = [

        {
            "question": "In web design, what does CSS stand for?",
            "answerOptions" : [ {"answerText" : "Cascading Style Sheet" , "correctAns" : "true" , "id":1 } ,
                                {"answerText" : "Counter Strike: Source" , "correctAns" : "false" , "id":2 } ,
                                {"answerText" : "Corrective Style Sheet" , "correctAns" : "flase" , "id":3 } ,
                                {"answerText" : "Computer Style Sheet" , "correctAns" : "false"  , "id":4 } ]
        },
    
    
        {
            "question": "Under what pseudonym did Stephen King publish five novels between 1977 and 1984?",
            "answerOptions" : [ {"answerText" : "Mark Twain" , "correctAns" : "false" , "id":5} ,
                                {"answerText" : "Richard Bachman" , "correctAns" : "true"  , "id":6} ,
                                {"answerText" : "J. D. Robb" , "correctAns" : "false"  , "id":7} ,
                                {"answerText" : "Lewis Carroll" , "correctAns" : "false"  , "id":8} ]
        },
    
        {
            "question": "Which modern day country is the region that was known as Phrygia in ancient times?",
            "answerOptions" : [ {"answerText" : "Greece" , "correctAns" : "false"  , "id":9} ,
                                {"answerText" : "Syria" , "correctAns" : "false"  , "id":10} ,
                                {"answerText" : "Egypt" , "correctAns" : "false" , "id":11 } ,
                                {"answerText" : "Turkey" , "correctAns" : "true"  , "id":12} ]
        },
    
    
        
    ]

    const quizQ = qanda.map(ques => <Quiz question={ques.question} answer1={ques.answerOptions[0].answerText}  answer2={ques.answerOptions[1].answerText}  
        answer3={ques.answerOptions[2].answerText}  answer4={ques.answerOptions[3].answerText} click={switchColor} clicked={color}  />)

   
    // function getId() {
    //     for(const i = 0 ; i > 3 ; i++) {
    //         const qId = qanda.map(ques => ques.answerOptions[i].id)
    //     }
    // }
 
   

 
    function switchIt() {

        setSwitch1(prevValue => !prevValue)
    }

    function switchColor() {

        setColor(prevValue => !prevValue)
        
        
    }


    return (
        <div className="body">

            

            {switch1 ? quizQ  : <Main onclick={switchIt}/> }



        </div>
    )

}
```

Quiz.js

```
import blob1 from './blob1.png'
import blob2 from './blob2.png'


export default function Quiz(props) {

    const style = {
        backgroundColor: props.clicked && '#D6DBF5',
        border: props.clicked && '#293264'
    }



    return (
        <div className='quiz-body'>
            <img src={blob1} className="blob1"/>
            <img src={blob2} className="blob2"/>

            <h2 className='h2-quiz'>{props.question}</h2>

            <button className='btn-ans' onClick={props.click}  style={style}>{props.answer1}</button>
            <button className='btn-ans' onClick={props.click}  style={style}>{props.answer2}</button>
            <button className='btn-ans' onClick={props.click}  style={style}>{props.answer3}</button>
            <button className='btn-ans' onClick={props.click}  style={style}>{props.answer4}</button>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <hr/>


            
        </div>
    )

}
```

Main.js

```
import blob1 from './blob1.png'
import blob2 from './blob2.png'


export default function Main(props) {
 
    


    return (
        <main>

            <img src={blob1} className="blob1"/>
            <h1 className='main-h1'>Quizzical</h1>
            <p className='main-description'>Welcome, to the Quizzical Quiz game.</p>
            <button className='main-button' onClick={props.onclick} >Start Quiz</button>
            <img src={blob2} className="blob2"/>

        </main>
    )

}
```

index.css

```
body {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    background-color: #F5F7FB;  
    font-family: 'karla' , sans-serif ;
}

/* Home Page Part */

main {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 40vh;
    
}

.main-h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 100px;
  
}

.main-description {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.main-button {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #4D5B9E;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 150px;
    border: none;
    color: #F5F7FB;
    font-family: 'karla' , sans-serif ;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.blob1 {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
}

.blob2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
}


/* Quiz Part */

.quiz-body {
   /* background-color: #4D5B9E;  */
   width: 65%;
   text-align: left;
   margin: auto;
}

.h2-quiz {
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:800;
}

.btn-ans {
    font-size: 15px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-family: 'karla';
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color:#F5F7FB ;
    border-radius: 10px ;


}
```

I am sorry if I have done the techniques wrong this is my first project after learning React

Comment: also: [Only one active button in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70570025/only-one-active-button-in-react), or [React, how to toggle background color of just one button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63519495/react-how-to-toggle-background-color-of-just-one-button)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use state to store the color. Maybe this would give you the idea how to solve the problem :

```
class Test extends React.Component {
constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
       black: true
    }
}

changeColor(){
   this.setState({black: !this.state.black})
}

render(){
    let btn_class = this.state.black ? "blackButton" : "whiteButton";

    return (
         <button className={btn_class} onClick=. 
 {this.changeColor.bind(this)}>
              Button
         </button>
    )
 }
}

React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

ej:https://jsfiddle.net/tkkqx2y2/

thnks to @user3350597 for response

Comment: This is a duplicate multiple times over, just flag to close instead of answering

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
const App = () => {
  const [style, setStyle] = useState(true);

  const changeStyle = () => {
    setStyle(!style);
  };
  return (
      <div className={style ? "cont" : "cont2"}>
        <button className="button" onClick={changeStyle}>
          Click me!
        </button>
      </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

```
.cont {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  background-color: violet;
}
.cont2 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :-

```js
import "./styles.css";
import "./App.css";
import { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(null);
  const handler = (i) => {
    setActive(i);
  };

  const btns = [
    { id: 0, title: "First Button" },
    { id: 1, title: "Second Button" },
    { id: 2, title: "Third Button" }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {btns.map((btn, i) => (
        <button
          key={i}
          className={i === active ? "active-btn" : "inactive-btn"}
          onClick={() => handler(i)}
        >
          {btn.title}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.inactive-btn {
  border: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  color: white;
  background: grey;
}
.active-btn {
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background: black;
}
```